# Animating the square with graphicsdropShadow in the frameless window PyQt

Tags: pyqt

I have a frameless window and i have set `WA_TranslucentBackground` to that window

And I have a square that I have set `graphicsdropshadow` on it

I am going to animate the square by pressing the button

but i get this error ->

```
UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(400, 126), size=(800x600), dirty=(745x745 -295, -285) (The parameter is incorrect.)
```

When I remove `WA_TranslucentBackground (While there are still graphicsdropshadow)` everything works fine

or if I don't remove the `WA_TranslucentBackground` and instead remove the `graphicsdropshadow` from the square everything works fine again

It seems that the square with `graphicsdropshadow` in the `WA_TranslucentBackground` does not animate properly

What exactly is the problem?

code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(600,600)      
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        button = QPushButton('Start',self, clicked=self.animation)
        button.move(500, 10)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
        self.frame.resize(100, 100)

        menuShadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
        menuShadow.setColor(QColor('#4E4E4E'))
        menuShadow.setOffset(0,0)
        menuShadow.setBlurRadius(10)
        self.frame.setGraphicsEffect(menuShadow)

    def animation(self):
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b'geometry')
        self.animation.setDuration(10000)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 100))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
        self.animation.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```